# Helm Subcharts values with Named Template getting null

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Using helm version 3.7.2.

I've tried many ways to implement named template to cover many cases, for example:
I have an umbrella chart structure that contains other subchart. I want to have the ability to define a         named template in subchart #1 and include it in other named template in subchart #2.

I have tried many things to accomplish that, the way I found that works well is: (simple example)

I have tried many things to accomplish that, the way I found that works well is: (simple example)

in subchart #1:
`{{- define "subchart1.ports" -}} 5678 {{- end -}}`

in subchart #2:
`... port: {{ include "subchart1.ports" .Subcharts.subchart1Name }} ...`

and it worked! I've read the keyword ".Subcharts" can exposed scopes between subcharts... I know between parent chart and subchart there's another ways, but I am talking about implementing this between subchats.

The **problem** is when I am doing the same thing but just mention a value.. case:

in subchart #1:
`{{- define "subchart1.ports" -}} {{ .Values.service.port }} {{- end -}}`

in subchart #2:
`... port: {{ include "subchart1.ports" .Subcharts.subchart1Name }} ...`

In any other "regular" named template let's say define and include at the same chart, I do not have this issue and I get the content of the value. I have made sure that this value is set and I even see it thru helm template command... but in the situation I have described, with using .Subchart and share it between subcharts I do not get the content of the value... I get null (when I pipe it toYaml..).

If there is a better way to achieve it, I'll be glad to hear or any insight about my case.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm curious where you read about `.Subcharts`.  I see it in [the source](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/863bc74e5ad090b97f69dcb643be8d969b07e7cf/pkg/engine/engine.go#L377), and it looks like it should work as you describe, if subchart2 depends on subchart1.  What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Same as you and I was surprised cause I didn’t see it in docs… actually sb2 doesn’t not depend on sb1, that’s the thing, they are all inside an “umbrella” chart, but NO subchart declared in Chart.yaml of other subchart.. but it works lol.. basically using .Subcharts keyword does exposed subcharts without any dependency declaration. Which is cool I guess and it works! When I define a port number hard-coded, it did appear in sb2 but when I use a value, it brings back null and not the value itself… which is weird cause this value declared in sb1 and also trying being used in named template in sb1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deep checking, as far as I know and see at the source code, the capability of using the .Subcharts is between sub-charts in an umbrella and not between the sub-charts to the root/main/global chart that holds the umbrella. It’s also relevant to tpl files and templating, there no way to point from a template to higher lever as long as it’s not between the sub-charts.